# Make methods execute synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, typescript

Good day, I am new to JavaScript/TypeScript and looking for generic solution to indicate that `ajax callback` has completed so that other code that depends on the outcome of callback can execute.

For example class Fee Calculator, it gets instantiated with a service type and method calculate fee is called in order to display a fee of the service for the customer to agree.

```
class FeeCalculator {

    private cost: number = 0;
    private serviceType: number = 0;
    private jsonAjax: JsonAjax = null; 

    constructor(serviceType: number) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
        this.jsonAjax = new JsonAjax("/tmaMaster/JSONServlet");
    }

    public calculateFee(): void {

        // First, get the cost of the service from DB 
        this.cost = this.getServiceCost();  

        // calculate the fee and display it
        // Now, this code would still be executed even if the callback
        // didn't complete and therefore this.cost = 0, 
        // fee will be calculated wrongly
        var fee: number = this.calculateTheFee(cost); 
        alert(fee);
    }

    getServiceCost = () => {
        // IntegerWrapper is not relevant to this problem - just a primitive wrapper
        var cost: IntegerWrapper = new IntegerWrapper();
        this.execute("getServiceCost", this.serviceType, cost, this.setServiceCost);
    }

    // This is the callback 
    setServiceCost = (cost: IntegerWrapper) => {
        this.cost = IntegerWrapper.primitiveValue;
    } 

    private getFeeForTheCost(cost: number): number {
        return cost / 4;     
    }

    execute(command: string, requestDto: any, responseDto: any, callback: (responseDto: any) => void) {
        var commandObject: JsonCommand = new JsonCommand(command, requestDto);
        this.jsonAjax.call(commandObject, responseDto, callback);
    }
}
```

Will also include JsonAjax class:

```
import JsonExternalizable = require("./JsonExternalizable");

class JsonAjax {

    private READY_STATUS_CODE = 4;
    private url: string;

    constructor(url: string) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    private isCompleted(request: XMLHttpRequest) {
        return request.readyState === this.READY_STATUS_CODE;
    }

    call(requestDto: any, responseDto: any, callback: (responseDto: JsonExternalizable) => any) {


        // Create a request
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Attach an event listener
        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            var completed = this.isCompleted(request);
            if (completed && callback != null) {
                /*
                 * N.B. PLease note that readFromJsonString returns void, therefore below line must be called sperately from line below.
                 */
                responseDto.readFromJsonString(request.responseText);
                callback(responseDto);
            }
        };
        // Specify the HTTP verb and URL
        request.open('POST', this.url, true);
        // Send the request
        request.send(JSON.stringify(requestDto));

    }
    toString() {
        return "JsonAjax";
    }
}

export = JsonAjax;
```

The question is how do I make sure that `calculateTheFee` strictly called after `getServiceCost` is complete in other words make functions execute synchronously?

**Ways I know of:**

1. Do all other steps that require the `cost` value in a callback
   itself. Not keen on that solution (what if there are more values
   that need to be extracted  from DB and all of them needed for
   calculation) readability of that code will decrease.
2. Use timeout (Not generic enough, as we don't know how big is what we querying and how long it needs to "sleep")

P.S. Preferably without using extra libraries and plugins (company requirement)

Comment: You could use observables: http://reactivex.io/

Comment: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) sound like a good idea here. The thing is, these are asynchronous operations by their nature; trying to force them to be synchronous is going to make your app seem even slower.

Comment: Thanks. Agree, but at the same time some bits have to be synchronous, otherwise the app simply doesn't work.

Comment: As @MikeMcCaughan mentioned Promises are the way to go. Check out this video - It's about Ionic - but concepts are explained nicely https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYympIG00Pk